# UITableViewCell - Load 25 cells - don't reuse

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have 25 table cells and I want to load all of them together, without reusing them.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid recycling table cells, you can just avoid calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

If you want to do a one-time initial load of all your cells, you can do something like this in the init method of your table's data source:

```
// myCellArray is an instance var of type NSMutableArray.
myCellArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tV cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [myCellArray addObject:cell];
}
```

This will keep the cells in memory, since they'd be retained by `myCellArray` for you.

To be more efficient, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method can be something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if ([myCellArray count] > indexPath.row) {
    return [myCellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
  return [self createCellAtRow:indexPath.row];
}
```

However, you want to be careful about using more memory than you think is needed, and avoid taking too much time initializing your table.  In many cases, your app is likely to appear faster and use less memory if you just use recycled cells in the standard way (as suggested, for example, in [the UITableViewDataSource docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't load them all together. But for "not-reusable" cells, you can make unique cell-reusable-identifiers. So, it system needs the same (first, second, third) cell — it can get already created one. And for new cells they will be created as needed.

And if you reeeeeally need to load all the cells at once, you can call

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

in viewDidLoad for every indexPath you needed.